# contiki + eclipse on windows

Tags: eclipse, windows, contiki

I'm trying to make contiki working on a cc2650, since I a little bit reluctant to the idea of using command line to do everything and I don't want to install a new operating system on my pc, I would like to use eclipse IDE on windows to do so.

Do anybody know if it is possible?
Davide.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I made it work.
It was not very difficult. I post here steps I follow so if somebody else, with just few toolchain skills has to do this, can use my experience and avoid to throw away a day of work.

First thing to do (obviously) is to download Eclipse for C/C++ developer, if you, like me, are already using TI CodeComposerStudio to program TI devices it should work (I've tested) without any modifications.

Then you need: make, gcc, gdb, g++. For this download cygwin (search it in google), run the installer and select these packages:

- gcc-core
- gcc-g++
- gdb
- make

Go on and install them.
Add cygwin\bin folder to PATH in windows Environment variables

After this open cygwin terminal, navigate to the directory you want to use for contiki and type:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki
```

This will download contiki sources. Remember that, with cygwin terminal you can not navigate outside cygwin installation folder, so contiki sources will reside inside cygwin folder.
Now it's done!
You only need to open Eclipse, File->import->C/C++->ExistingCode as Makefile project, select an example from contiki/examples and import it (remember to select Cygwin GCC).

To modify make command for your target: project properties->C/C++ Build, uncheck 'Use default build command' and write your command, in my case I'm working with TI sensorTag so I use:

```
  make TARGET=srf06-cc26xx BOARD=sensortag/cc2650 cc26xx-web-demo.bin CPU_FAMILY=cc26xx
```

Actually I get an error after these steps. It was something related to the creation of .hex file (at least I think) so if you need only the .bin you can discard that error. But if you want to cancel it from console simply download SRecord from [here](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/) and put executable files inside cygwin\bin  (in this way you don't have to add another folder to PATH in Environment variables).

With these steps you can easily compile contiki, as said you can not upload binary to the target, for that you have to use other tools. In my case I use Flash Programmer 2 from TI which perfectly works as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You'll need to install `make` and the required compiler. And you'll need to configure Eclipse to invoke `make`. Using the Eclipse build system will not work. If you run Contiki's Makefiles with `V=1`, Eclipse will be able to parse the output. This is very handy as it enables the correct resolution of macros and `#ifdef` sections. You might need to make some adjustments to the configuration of the parer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Eclipse, but to flash programs to the motes you'll probably need to use the command line, especially if make & upload are not used to upload the program on command line. E.g. to flash openmote (cc2538) you cannot use make & upload, instead you need to use J-TAG Debugger or python bsl script. Therefore, according to your needs you will have to see if Eclipse will be useful else you just keep juggling between Eclipse and command line anyway.
  I have seen programming editor like geany helps a lot, as it is simple and has many features. But I compile and upload using the command line as usual

Comment: You can still invoke all those commands from eclipse by adding them as "tools".